# Visual Studio 2005 Basic Knowledge - How doing debugging on C# codes

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

My knowledge is very limited on VS in fact it's the first time I am using it and very little I know of C debugging too.

I have pre-existing .c and .o files that have been transferred into my folder and I open VS to edit them. I then compile on a unix windows with the icl command. What I get is obviously error messages because those files have been run in Linux compilers and never into Windows ones.

In blogs I always find mention to changing project properties when it's about resolving, i.e. _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE warnings or other types of errors. My problem is that I don't see those .c files as projects when I open them from VS so I cannot change those properties.

Do I have to turn them into projects? Or do I have to simply move them into folder where VS opens files from by default?

Help is needed, please.

Thanks
F

Comment: If you post exact text from the warnings and errors, especially if you also post the lines of code that have the errors, people may be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use .c file in a C# project, it is a completely different language.  Forums cannot really provide you with a short-cut for basic knowledge and skills you'll need to acquire to bring this project to a good end.  You'll need to take the time, experiment, read a few books.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quess. This assumes that your code is not dependent on anything.

1. You should create a C project (you may have to use empty project)
2. Add your c files to the project.
3. Right click solution and hit build.